# Excel: Averaging 15 minute streamflow measurements to create average daily streamflow measurment

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like take the 15 minute interval data points in column E and create an average for the day in column F. Date and time have been grouped into one cell from the data center. There is approximately 10,000 data points so I would like to keep column F as clean as possible - 1 number that is the average for that day.[image: USGS Streamflow Data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the first cell in which the formula is being placed is F2:

```
=IF(Day(C2)<>Day(C3),AVERAGEIFS(E:E,C:C,">=" & Int(C2),C:C,"<" & INT(C3)),"")
```

If the day changes then it puts the average of all the values between 0:00 of that day and less than 0:00 of the next.

If the day does not change then it fills the box with an empty string.

Put in F2 then copy/drag down.

This only works if the data is sorted on column C